# Is $d$ in the span(a,b,c) and span(a,b)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have he vectors $a=(1,2,6)$   $b=(4,6,6)$ $c=(6,8,9)$ 
Is $d=(6,6,6)$ in the span(a,b,c) and span(a,b).
First I found that the vectors a,b,c are dependent 
$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 4 & 6\\
  0 & 1 & 2\\
  0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$ then I add $d$ and reduce to 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 4 & 6 & 6 \\
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 & 3 & 8
\end{pmatrix} what do I do now?

Comment: Look at the bottom row. That tells you

Comment: Should I do $3z=8, z=8/3$ then $1y+2*(8/3)=3$ and so on?

Comment: Yes, you could, but essentially you know for part a) that $d$ is in the span, right?

Comment: nope I dont understand. Why is that right?

Comment: If you are on a $3$-dimensional vector space and $a,b,c$ are linearly independent vectors then they form a basis, right? So, their span is the whole space.

Comment: yea we are in $\Bbb R^3$ but why are the vectors independent? with the first matrix I think i show that they are dependent

Comment: Have a look at the matrix you got $\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 4 & 6\\
  0 & 1 & 2\\
  0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Ok so its linearly independent, but that doesnt mean it spans $\Bbb R^3$ right?

Comment: It means that. Three linearly independent vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3.$ They form a basis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69027/discussion-between-yolo-expectz-and-mfl).